# PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in

Tags: pdo

i made this code:

```
class Consultas{

    public function insertarUsuario($arg_nombre, $arg_usuario, $arg_passwd){
        $modelo = new Conexion();
        $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
        $sql = "insert into tablausuarios (nombre, usuario,password) values(:nombre, :usu, :passw)";
        $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':nombre', $arg_nombre);
        $statement->bindParam(':usuario', $arg_usuario);
        $statement->bindParam(':password', $arg_passwd);
        if($statement->execute(array(":nombre"=>$arg_nombre, ":usuario"=>$arg_usuario, ":password"=>$arg_passwd))){
            return "Registro creado satisfactoriamente";

        }else{

            return "error al crear registro";
        }
    }
```

and have this error: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating the bind param thing. and your parameter isn't the same on your execute method. I've updated code for you try with it.

**Update this code to like this:**

```
class Consultas{

public function insertarUsuario($arg_nombre, $arg_usuario, $arg_passwd){
    $modelo = new Conexion();
    $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
    $sql = "insert into tablausuarios (nombre, usuario,password) values(:nombre, :usu, :passw)";
    $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
    if($statement->execute(array(":nombre"=>$arg_nombre, ":usu"=>$arg_usuario, ":passw"=>$arg_passwd))){
        return "Registro creado satisfactoriamente";

    }else{

        return "error al crear registro";
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   class Consultas{

      public function insertarUsuario($arg_nombre, $arg_usuario, $arg_passwd){
      $modelo = new Conexion();
      $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
      $statement = $conexion->prepare("insert into tablausuarios (nombre, usuario,password) values (?,?,?)");
      if($statement->execute(array($arg_nombre,$arg_usuario,$arg_passwd))){
          return "Registro creado satisfactoriamente";

      }else{

          return "error al crear registro";
       }
    }
```

try this suggestion i think that it help you